String Attribute "coder" 1/0
I'm struggling with a problem right now.
I basically have two strings. I read the first from an Excel file and the second from the file name of another file. The hashcode method I overwritten returns different values ​​for both strings, even though their content is the same.
So I have the problem that my HashMap doesn't work properly because I use the string in question as the key
I discovered that the encoding is different. I can also tell from the “coder”.


My idea was to manually adjust the affected attributes for all objects. But that didn't help.
 public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = new String(name.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

I have experimented with apache tika, but unfortunately without success
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>

Methods in the Driver Class:
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Driver other = (Driver) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (surname == null) {
        if (other.surname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
        return false;
    return true;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public int compareTo(Driver o) {
    String d1Name = replaceUmlaute(o.getName());
    String d2Name = replaceUmlaute(this.getName());
    String d1Surname = replaceUmlaute(o.getSurname());
    String d2Surname = replaceUmlaute(this.getSurname());

    if (d1Name.compareToIgnoreCase(d2Name) == 0 && d1Surname.compareToIgnoreCase(d2Surname) == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if(o.hashCode() == this.hashCode()){
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private static String replaceUmlaute(String output) {
    String newString = output.replace("\u00fc", "ue")
            .replace("\u00f6", "oe")
            .replace("\u00e4", "ae")
            .replace("\u00df", "ss")
            .replaceAll("\u00dc(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Ue")
            .replaceAll("\u00d6(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Oe")
            .replaceAll("\u00c4(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Ae")
            .replace("\u00dc", "UE")
            .replace("\u00d6", "OE")
            .replace("\u00c4", "AE");
    return newString;
}

What can I do?
Does somebody has any idea?

documentation of hashCode(): "If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result."

this.name = new String(name.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); Yes, that makes no sense at all. What does this print? name.codePoints().mapToObj(c ->String.format("%04x ", c)).forEach(System.out::print);

Expanding on the comment from g00se: in Java, all strings use the same encoding for their internal representation. What might be the case is that the two strings appear the same but actually contain characters with different Unicode code points. The best way to handle this is by normalising them somehow when you read them in. You might need to use a third party library for this, or expand replaceUmlaute to handle more characters from other languages.

@TimMoore that is incorrect; strings do not use the same encoding for their internal representation. There's LATIN1 representation and UTF8. What you say used to be true, but 'used to' is, at this point, well over a decade ago. There is no normalizing this because it depends on locale.

@Sagm1 the 'coder' used does not affect equals nor does it affect hashCode - hence, futzing with that won't make a difference. Your two strings aren't equal. Period. They merely look identical. Go through it codepoint by codepoint and compare by hand. Soon enough you'll find the difference. Note that the unicode table is loaded to the gills with 'stuff that looks identical in every way' and 'different sequences of chars that look identical' (such as ë and 'e' and 'put a ¨ on previous' which is a unicode character), or 'turkish dotless I capital' and ascii 'I' - identical in looks.

@Sagm1 your compareTo method is broken. The javadoc tells you more: It must be consistent. And it is not. Driver 'A' comes before driver 'B' as per your compareTo, and driver 'B' comes before 'A' - which is inconsistent. You have to fix it. Treating 2 things equal if their hashCode is equal, is also broken. You are fixing non-problems. Remove all your attempts - and recheck your strings. They are not equal, that is the problem.

One string uses precomposed characters, the other uses combining accents. You can tell from the lengths. One "Ergüz" is 5 bytes, one for each LATIN1 character. The other is 12 bytes, two for each of six UTF-16 code units; one each for the letters plus one for the Unicode Combining Diaeresis after the "u". Use java.text.Normalizer to convert them both to either NFC, canonical composition, or NFD, canonical decomposition.

nit: new String(..., Charset.forName("UTF-8")) is silly, you still have to deal with unsupported charset exceptions. Might as well use new String(..., "UTF-8"). What you should be using is new String(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8). But there's no point converting to bytes and back to a string, since that has nothing to do with your problem.

@rzwitserloot I’ve never heard this about strings being represented internally using Latin-1 or UTF-8. Do you have a reference? The doc for java.lang.String in Java 21 still says “A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs”. In any case, even if some specific implementation has optimised this, the same string would not produce different has codes in the same JVM instance, correct?

@Tim yes, strings are always represented as UTF-16, but internally the characters are stored in a byte[] using either Latin1 or UTF-16 encoding - source code, see also the non-public  java.lang.StringLatin1 and javav.lang.StringUTF16 (this distinction is normally not visible)

@Tim just found the JEP: see JEP 254: Compact Strings (since Java 9) -- but the internal storage mode is not relevant for this question - the String class hides that detail - as you wrote, it will not produce different results

@Tim as my other comment said, the internal representation does not affect the hashCode. But, you're the one said 'java always represents strings using the same encoding in its internal representation' - I was correcting that error.

I apologise for the inaccuracy. Indeed I did not realise that this was implemented by default after the optional flag was added in JDK 6. Thanks for pointing it out. Nonetheless, I think the essence of what we’re saying is the same. Even with compact strings, any given sequence of code points will always have the same representation within a particular JVM instance, but two strings can look the same while being a different sequence of code points.

I also didn’t realise that java.text.Normaliser is part of the JDK, but that does look like the best solution. @DavidConrad do you want to write that as an answer?

No, Normalizer might help but it won't by any means be a panacea. The only time that can really help you is when you have diacritics as separate codepoints. It's not going to magically turn o umlaut into oe for example

Sure, but isn’t the problem in this question that they have diacritics as separate code points?

Possibly but so far we've been talking somewhat theoretically. We need to see actual examples
